# How to navigate two outlets deep?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

The URL I would like to generate is:
*http://localhost:8000/Home/(fooOutlet:foo/(barOutlet:bar))*

I have a router-outlet named 'Foo' and it contains a router-outlet named 'Bar'.
How can I show a component in Bar?
I created the codes below, but it doesn't do the trick:

```
this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { fooOutlet: 'foo', barOutlet: 'bar' } }], );
this._router.navigate([{ outlets: [{ fooOutlet: 'foo' }, { barOutlet: 'bar' }] }]);
```

It gives me this:

> (fooOutlet:foo//barOutlet:bar)

But I need:

> (fooOutlet:foo/(barOutlet:bar))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show component in nested router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381534/show-component-in-nested-router)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { fooOutlet: 'foo'} },{ outlets: { barOutlet: 'bar'} }] );
```

I think your error is because when you call the method navigate in the way that you are doing is to show outlets that are at the same level (deep),

Comment: I create this demo to reproduce your issue and I m having it https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-deep-routing, I will investigate more about it

Comment: What I used to do, was navigate to levelA, and from there navigate to levelB, but we want to go there in 1 click.

Comment: I'm afraid there is a bug in the framework: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18928

Comment: try a workaround, In ngOnInit()  from the first component listen to a specific parameter, if this parameter comes then navigate to the next componet