# Show component in nested router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

[image: Routersetup]
I want to route to "config" router, which is nested 2 outlets deep but I'm unable to figure out the correct way to do so.

```html
<router>
  <router name="main">
    <router name="config">
    </router>
  </router>
</router>
```

In my routing.ts, I created 2 ways to reach the component:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    // Entrypoint.
    path: 'Foo', component: FooComponent, canActivate: [IsServerOnlineGuard], children: [
        path: 'Bar', component: BarComponent, outlet: 'main', children: [
          { path: 'Smtp', component: smtpComponent, outlet: 'config' } // registered as a child
        ],
        path: 'Smtp', component: smtpComponent, outlet: 'config' }, // registered under the "main" component
      },
    ]
  },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'CSI' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'CSI' },
];
```

I tried navigating there  in 2 ways.

```js
public RouteToConfigOutlet(componentName: string) {
  this._router.navigate([`/(main:BarComponent)/`, {
    outlets: {
      config: ['Smtp']
    }
  }]);
}

public RouteToConfigOutlet(componentName: string) {
  this._router.navigate([``, {
    outlets: {
      main: ['BarComponent'],
      config: ['Smtp']
    }
  }]);
}
```

Alas I'm unable to get my component to show up and am trying to find the correct way to get there.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [this website](https://www.mckennaconsultants.com/nesting-router-outlets-in-angular-6-7/).
The correct way of routing is:

```
router.navigate(
[{
   outlets: {
      'main': ['BarComponent',
         { outlets: { 'config': ['smtpComponent'] } } ]
   }
}]);
```